# how to do a macro in excel the do a vlookup with dynamic variable that i get from the user (not in the excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro on Excel that does a vlookup for a table that have 2 columns (amount, code)
I'm getting the amount from the user (not in in a cell in the Excel file) - and the macro will return the code at the same row

example table

[image]

the macro I wrote

sum - the amount I'm searching for in the table.
sRes - the return value unless I don't need it.

```
sub SEARCH ()
    Dim sum As string
    Dim sRes As string
    Worksheets("table").Activate
        sRes = Application.Vlookup(sum, shData.Range("A2:B11"),2)
        Deug.Print sRes
End Sub
```

this is the last macro I wrote (the Hebrew after Worksheets is the name..)
I tried a lot of options (this is the last one I tried), but nothing worked

1. not getting the value by a variable from outside the macro.
2. getting the answer in a variable so I could use it outside the macro.

Comment: Is ShData anything?

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) • Check out the [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) to get a value from the user.

Comment: shData.Range - that what it showed me when I searched for the answer

Comment: Do you get any errors? If yes where and which? Try something like `sum = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Value", Type:=1)` before the Vlookup line.

Comment: I searched the Application.InputBox - it showed me a dialog box 
I dont want a Dialog box - I only want the macro to get the value from outside without any messages (it's like I have a function that have this number somehow (calculate it) and send it to the macro...)

Comment: HAVE TO GO NOW 
SO I WILL CHECK IT LATER

Comment: You can either read the value from a cell or you can let the user enter a value in a input box. First you need to be clear where exactly that value is saved otherwise we cannot help you. The macro needs to read it otherwise it cannot know it.

Comment: You are not setting shData, try `worksheets("sheetofinterest").range("a2:b11")`

Comment: the value is stored in a variable called amount (in the outer function that runs the macro)
@Nathan_Sav and what should I do with the range inside the Vlookup?

Comment: @DanielLichtenstadt Then show that outher function and how the macro gets called please.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it's Via the program Kryon macro func
the macro is getting called through this program (all the values that I need - will be set before the macro...)
and I only need to set the value outside the macro and it will take it from there (I just checked it with a friend)
so the Q is how do I do the Vlookup?

Comment: Also, should this not be a function rather than a sub? `Function MyVlookup(inputParam as integer) as variant`

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change how that macro calls your procedure and submit a value as parameter:
Declare your procedure as follows:

```
Sub SEARCH(ByVal MyValueVariable As Variant)
    Dim sRes As string
    Worksheets("table").Activate
    sRes = Application.Vlookup(MyValueVariable, shData.Range("A2:B11"),2)
    Debug.Print sRes
End Sub
```

And make sure your other macro submits a value like

```
Call SEARCH(12345)
```

where `12345` is the value you want to lookup.

---

\ Edit according comment

If `SEARCH` should return a value you need to make it a function instead of a procedure:

```
Function SEARCH(ByVal MyValueVariable As Variant) As Variant
    Dim sRes As string
    Worksheets("table").Activate
    sRes = Application.Vlookup(MyValueVariable, shData.Range("A2:B11"),2)
    Debug.Print sRes
    SEARCH = sRes 'return value
End Function
```

Then you need to do the following to call it from your other macro

```
Dim MyReturnValue As Variant
MyReturnValue = SEARCH(12345)

'now MyReturnValue contains the result of the search function
```

Comment: I will check it later for some reason my excel and program doesnt work
thank u very much
But if I want that the macro will send the result outside the Excel back to the program - don't I need to declare the sRes as variant also? 
or the "sRes=..."   is enough?

Comment: @DanielLichtenstadt I recommend you to read some basic instructions about how to use procedures and functions. See my edit above for how to return a value.